# How to redirect wav to mp3 in htaccess if wav file not found?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

At the root of the web server are audio files. Files can be in wav or mp3 format. I am trying to redirect to a file with the same name, but with a different extension. For example, if there is no file with the name hello.wav, redirect to hello.mp3. My attempts were on the example of one answer about html and php. Please correct me!

Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian 9.8)

my .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.wav$ $1.mp3 [L]
```

For example, if there is no file with the name hello.wav, redirect to hello.mp3. in browser i am write http://domain.kz/hello.wav and should get http://domain.kz/hello.mp3

Comment: I made a simple mistake in not having completely checked all the settings of the web server. I turned on the modules "rewrite" and "userdir", and edited AllowOverride for /var/www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple mistake in not having completely checked all the settings of the web server. I turned on the modules "rewrite" and "userdir"

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

and edited AllowOverride for /var/www/

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride **All**
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and restart apache

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your problem is solved, but I found a lead that might help you.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s

```
# Does the file exist?
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" "!-f"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" "!-d"
# Create an if-then-else construct by skipping 3 lines if we meant to go to the "else" stanza.
RewriteRule ".?" "-" [S=3]

# IF the file exists, then:
    RewriteRule "(.*\.gif)" "images.php?$1"
    RewriteRule "(.*\.html)" "docs.php?$1"
    # Skip past the "else" stanza.
    RewriteRule ".?" "-" [S=1]
# ELSE...
    RewriteRule "(.*)" "404.php?file=$1"
# END
```